# How to hide element depending on clicked area? Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I need your help. I have 2 items `checkbox` and `textarea`. I want to make the following logic: at first I could see these 2 elements, but when I start typing something in `textarea` or just click on `textarea` to enter text there, my `checkbox` disappeared, and when I clicked outside `textarea`, `checkbox` appeared. For starters, I'm trying to make logic to check if the cursor is clicked on textarea, but I don't know how to do it? How to hide a `checkbox` depending on whether the cursor is `clicked` on textarea? Thank you very much)

html

```
<mat-checkbox
   (change)="saveMessage($event)"
   formControlName="checkboxInviteMessage"
   [disabled]="form.controls.inviteMessage.value?.length < 1">
   // *ngIf = "textarea is not focused / blured">
</mat-checkbox>

<textarea formControlName="inviteMessage" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onFocus()"></textarea>
```

ts

```
onFocus(event: any) {
  if (event) {
    this.selectedItem = event.target;
  } else {
    this.selectedItem = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically do what the answer suggests, I made a small example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nztu8y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @MikeS. Please, last request to you. If you wrote that code, could you show me how to make a false checkbox if we make changes? For instance, i wrote something and then pressed checkbox, but then i decided to make changes. Is is possible to make checkbox false, if we typing in textarea text again? Thank you very much

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz with a second example. Using `ngModel`, you can programmatically set the value of the checkbox, when the `input` event of the textarea is fired.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you use a variable defined in .ts

```
isFocus:boolean=false;
```

Then use *ngIf to show/not an element and the events (focus) and (blur) to give value to the variable

```
<mat-checkbox *ngIf="!isFocus" ...>

</mat-checkbox>

<textarea formControlName="inviteMessage" (focus)="isFocus=true"
             (blur)="isFocus=false"></textarea>
```

See that for simple instructions you can use the own .html and is not necesary create a function in .ts

Is your two inputs are in a loop, you need an array of variables

```
isFocus:boolean[]=[];

<ng-container *ngFor="let ...;let i=index">
    <mat-checkbox *ngIf="!isFocus[i]" ...>
    
    </mat-checkbox>
    
    <textarea formControlName="inviteMessage" (focus)="isFocus[i]=true"
                 (blur)="isFocus[i]=false"></textarea>
</ng-container>
```